# Dealing with ZipAlign with Ionic (Android Builds)

Tags: android, ionic-framework, apk

I'm signing an android build and got to the end to come across "Zipalign is not recognized"

After Googling and looking on Stack, zipalign seems to exist in the build directory of the Android path. (eg. C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.2)

Going forward with apk builds, should the signed apk be placed in the build tools directory or the zipalign.exe be moved to the App folder (eg. C:\Users\Me\Desktop\MyApp\platforms\android\build\outputs\apk)

Then the zip align command run like so:
zipalign -v 4 HelloWorld-release-unsigned.apk HelloWorld.apk

Comment: it should be in build tool directory .what command are you using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your command should be like this

```
path-to-your-android-sdk/build-tools/21.1.2/zipalign  -v 4 android-release-unsigned.apk HelloWorld.apk
```

Also make sure you have used these commands for generating unsigned apk in your \platforms\android\build\outputs\apk directory

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore "YOURAPP-key.keystore" android-release-unsigned.apk yourApp


jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs android-release-unsigned.apkjarsigner -verify -verbose -certs android-release-unsigned.apk
```

Hope This helps you . Thanks :)

Comment: Even though my path is correct it doesn't seem to like it when I try ```C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.2 zipalign -v 4 android-release-unsigned.apk myapp.apk```   Resulting in "is not recognised as an internal command"....

Comment: what if you use like this /Users/Me/AppData/Local/AppData/sdk/build-tools/23.0.2 zipalign -v 4 HelloWorld-release-unsigned.apk HelloWorld.apk

Comment: No joy with that either, I assume moving the zipalign tool to the outputs folder or the apk to the built tools folder and running a shorter command is the easier solution. Just though there would be a standard practise on how this should be done, hence my post on Stack.

Comment: In the end I moved the unsigned apk and keystore to
"C:\Users\ME\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.2" 
Then I ran "zipalign -v 4 HelloWorld-release-unsigned.apk HelloWorld.apk". It just wouldn't work with the paths included this way I got a successful APK build.

Answer (score 2):

Within git bash I typed:

```
$ [path_to_sdk_folder]/build-tools/26.0.1/zipalign -v 4 C:/Users/your_user_name_on_windows/ionicprojects/myap2/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-release-unsigned.apk myap2.apk
```

Replace backslashes with forward slashes, worked for me. Yet another why? I don't know.

myap2.apk created in my app current directory that contains config.xml file

Backslashes do not work just use forward slashes!